# Why does service runs as root while USERNAME is set to something else

Tags: bash, upstart

I am setting up a Linux service for my Python app using Upstart. Here is the `conf` file in /etc/init/

```
description "AAE client app"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

env PATH=/home/ec2-user/aae_client/env/bin
env PROGRAM_NAME="aae"
env USERNAME="ec2-user"

# Main script to be run
script
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Ready to run..." >> /var/log/$PROGRAM_NAME.sys.log

    export HOME="/home/ec2-user"
    echo $$ > /var/run/$PROGRAM_NAME.pid

    cd /home/ec2-user/aae_client
    exec python -m app.run >> /var/log/$PROGRAM_NAME.sys.log 2>&1
end script
```

I already set the `USERNAME` to `ec2-user`. However when I run the service, it shows it is run by `root`. Apparently other variables such as `PATH` are set correctly. Why does it still run as root when USERNAME is specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `USERNAME` or even the canonical `USER` variable does not change the context the processes run in. Have a look at the [solutions over at SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/213416/running-upstart-jobs-as-unprivileged-users).